# make command fails

Tags: lubuntu, make, makefile

Hello Im completly new to Lubuntu(started this weekend).
The first thing i want to install give me know a lot of trouble for this time.

I want to install a driver for the Novation Launchapad. I have downloaded the driver from: [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/drivernovationl/)

Here is a Makefile thing with and as far i know can found i go to the download location and type 'make' and it should be working.

but i get the following error:

```
name@myname-lubuntu:~/Downloads/movolaunch$ make Makefile
The program 'make' can be found in the following packages:
 * make
 * make-guile
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
winkelk@winkelk-lubuntu:~/Downloads/movolaunch$
```

I have no idea how i can fix this.
On [railbridge.org](http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/linux) i read that in the terminal "run command as a login shell" must checked on. But that does'nt matter.

I hope anybody can help.

Thanks

Comment: May I suggest to read the error message provided and follow its advice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"make" does not exist on your system, you need to install it using

```
sudo apt-get install make
```

Then you will be able to run your make command